# GLMM for panel data: fixed-effect, random-effect, or mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, glmm

I am using data from the Medical Expenditure Panel Survey (MEPS) to create panel data. My question is whether it is appropriate to include dummy variables, a fixed-effect term, and a random-effects term in one model. I will be using R for this analysis.

For simplicity, my data is structured as follows

| Person | Household | ID | Insurance | Primary Care Visits | Costs | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1A | 1 | 5 | 1,000 | 2015 |
| 1 | A | 1A | 1 | 7 | 1,025 | 2016 |
| 1 | A | 1A | 1 | 9 | 1,025 | 2017 |
| 2 | A | 2A | 1 | 3 | 750 | 2015 |
| 2 | A | 2A | 1 | 2 | 300 | 2016 |
| 2 | A | 2A | 1 | 6 | 650 | 2017 |
| 3 | B | 3B | 2 | 10 | 2,750 | 2015 |
| 3 | B | 3B | 2 | 12 | 2,300 | 2016 |
| 3 | B | 3B | 2 | 19 | 3,650 | 2017 |

Each row represents a unique person per year within a household. Some individuals live within the same household, like persons 1 and 2.

My research question is to understand how insurance and the number of primary care visits influence the total cost of care.

If this is my general model: $$ Cost_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1(Insurance)_{it} + \beta_2(Primary Care Visits)_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$$

My questions:

1. Is it appropriate to add a fixed-effects term $$\alpha_i$$ to account for other individual-level unobserved time-invariant factors? Or, will adding this term absorb the effect of insurance?
2. To account for the cluster effect of people being in a household, should I include a random effect $$u_i$$? I don't care about knowing the estimates for each household, but rather need to capture that individuals live in a household, and thus their insurance and primary care visit behaviors are correlated with each other and potentially the total cost. Would it make more sense to include a dummy variable for 'household size greater than 1 (self)'?
3. If I were to include both ai and ui in the original model, would that be appropriate to capture all unobserved time-invariant and time-variant individual-level characteristics?

Please let me know if I made any conceptual errors in my understanding of this or if there are other approaches to account for this type of panel data. Thank you.